# Create a flag with closest value from a column in R

Tags: r

I have a df(refer below) where I need to create a flag based on a column in the df .The falg should be based on a predefined values.

```
Year    Month   Budget   percentage_change 
2014    Feb  $ 2,285,940     61.993 
2014    Feb  $ 2,294,280     62.219 
2014    Feb  $ 2,356,192     63.898 
2014    Feb  $ 2,356,192     63.898 
2014    Feb  $ 2,359,000     64.000 
2014    Feb  $ 2,359,255     65.000 
2014    Feb  $ 2,359,372     70.000 
2015    Feb  $ 2,465,829     68.905 
2015    Feb  $ 2,475,187     68.912 
2015    Feb  $ 2,475,596     68.918 
2015    Feb  $ 2,480,543     69.472 
2015    Feb  $ 2,499,953     69.472 
2015    Feb  $ 2,500,021     69.702 
2015    Feb  $ 2,503,888     69.787 
2015    Feb  $ 2,503,888     70.041
```

The desired output I am looking for is mentioned below

```
Year    Month          Budget   percentage_change Flag
2014    Feb  $        2,285,940          61.993     0
2014    Feb  $        2,294,280          62.219     0
2014    Feb  $        2,356,192          63.898     0
2014    Feb  $        2,356,192          63.898     0
2014    Feb  $        2,359,000          64.000     0
2014    Feb  $        2,359,255          65.000     0
2014    Feb  $        2,359,372          70.000     1
2015    Feb  $        2,465,829          68.905     0
2015    Feb  $        2,475,187          68.912     0
2015    Feb  $        2,475,596          68.918     0
2015    Feb  $        2,480,543          69.472     0
2015    Feb  $        2,499,953          69.472     0
2015    Feb  $        2,500,021          69.702     0
2015    Feb  $        2,503,888          69.787     0
2015    Feb  $        2,503,888          70.041     1
```

Where the flag created is based on value where the percentage change column value is nearest to 71.

The problem  I have is the data is long and the percentage get repetative after every certain inverval based on Year and Month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data is in a `data.frame` named `mydf`. We need to perform this operation on groups, so we can use `dplyr` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf <- mydf %>%
    group_by(Year, Month) %>%
    mutate(Flag = ifelse(abs(percentage_change - 71) == min(abs(percentage_change - 71)), 1, 0))

mydf
        Year  Month    Budget percentage_change  Flag
    1   2014    Feb 2,285,940            61.993     0
    2   2014    Feb 2,294,280            62.219     0
    3   2014    Feb 2,356,192            63.898     0
    4   2014    Feb 2,356,192            63.898     0
    5   2014    Feb 2,359,000            64.000     0
    6   2014    Feb 2,359,255            65.000     0
    7   2014    Feb 2,359,372            70.000     1
    8   2015    Feb 2,465,829            68.905     0
    9   2015    Feb 2,475,187            68.912     0
    10  2015    Feb 2,475,596            68.918     0
    11  2015    Feb 2,480,543            69.472     0
    12  2015    Feb 2,499,953            69.472     0
    13  2015    Feb 2,500,021            69.702     0
    14  2015    Feb 2,503,888            69.787     0
    15  2015    Feb 2,503,888            70.041     1
```

Comment: Thank you @bouncyball.This worked for me with little addition to the code with as.numeric before the if else .The final code looks like

mydf <- mydf %>%
    group_by(Year, Month) %>%
    mutate(Flag = as.numeric (ifelse(abs(percentage_change - 71) == min(abs(percentage_change - 71)), 1, 0)))

which neglected the error #incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector for mutate use.

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract the column from the predefined value, take the absolute value, and find the minimum.

Here's a function so it can be reproduced over multiple datasets and multiple columns:

```
createFlag <- function(column, value) {
  return(ifelse(abs(column-value)==min(abs(column-value), na.rm=T), 1, 0))
}

mydf$Flag <- createFlag(mydf$percentage_change, 71)
```